# Run as Eclipse Application

Tags: eclipse, emf

I am following an Eclipse Modeling Framework [tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseEMF/article.html) (and also [this one](http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/tutorials/emf-tutorial/)). At one of the steps, I need to run a project (the .editor project according to the tutorial) by right clicking on it and selecting **Run As -> Eclipse Application**. But there is no such item in my eclipse!. I can only see "Java Application" and "Java Applet" in Run sub-menu.

(I am using eclipse-java-kepler-R-win32-x86_64.)

Comment: Are you sure you are right click on a plug-in project, 'Eclipse Application' will only appear for plug-ins

Comment: Yeah I am sure it is. (According to the tutorial, it is the "model editor project" and is supposed to be able to run as eclipse application.

Comment: Do you mean the .editor project?

Comment: Yes (my post is now edited)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I installed **Eclipse Plugin Development Tools** (from Help -> Install New Software...) and now,  Can run as Eclipse application :)

Running as Eclipse application starts a new instance of Eclipse with the plugin projects installed (the generated projects in my case). So, it takes a lot of memory and can slow down the system. You can export the projects as a plugin for a better performance. you can use lots of available tutorials like this [vogella tutorial for Eclipse plug-in development](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipsePlugIn/article.html).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it took me 10 more minutes to find out the proper URL of the repository ;-)
Eclipse -> Install New Software -> Add repository -> Location: http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/x.x (nowadays x.x = 4.3)

Comment: more intuitive answer including url example is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29675013/eclipse-missing-eclipse-application-launch-configuration