# Eclipse: missing eclipse application launch configuration

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I want to choose an Eclipse Application Launch configuration in the Run/Debug Configuration of eclipse, for running an eclipse plugin, but it doesnt exists.

How can I add the Eclipse Application Launch configurations in the run/debug configurations. I'm using Eclipse Luna IDE for Java Developers.

Comment: Your first sentence is a bit unclear.  Can you rephrase it?

Comment: Well what is it you want to launch? Do you have a xxx.product file or something like that?

Comment: Had the same issue. Installing the Eclipse SDK from the eclipse install site added the eclipse application launch configuration

Answer (score 6):

You are missing the **Eclipse Project SDK**, which is needed to create Eclipse Applications. *Without* it, you will notice for example these problems:

- The *Run/Debug configuration* is missing a category "Eclipse Applications" (as you mentioned)
- The *Windows / Preferences* dialog is missing a category "Plug-in Development"
- Importing launch configurations for "Eclipse Applications" will have no effect.

You **install** the *Eclipse Project SDK* like this:

- Help / Install New Software...
- Choose the installation repository. In case of Eclipse Oxygen, it is *"Oxygen - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/oxygen"*
- Filter for **Eclipse Project SDK**
- Check it & press "Finish"

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I have Eclipse Project SDK installed, I have restarted, and Run As -> Eclipse Applications is still missing. Am I missing anything else?

Comment: @Fred I made the same mistake as you. Make sure to wait for the installation to finish, you can click on the green icon at the bottom right to see the progress.